# Is "left for heaven" a common phrase in English?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Is "left for heaven" a common phrase for native English speakers?

Comment: Probably not what you were looking for, but an expression that used to be popular is "leave it to heaven"; very similair, but a different meaning, methinks.

Comment: Not familiar to me, in the US Midwest.

Comment: it simply means the person has passed away. and settled in heaven..!!>

Comment: In answer to the question: "No."

Answer (score 4):

Corpus evidence suggests that it is not. There are no records for it in the Corpus of Contemporary American English or the British National Corpus, and there are only six records in the Corpus of Global Web-Based English of 1.9 billion words from 20 countries.

Answer (score 4):

"Left for heavenly abode" is a common Indian English idiom, a euphemism used mainly in obituary notices.

[malankaradailynews](http://malankaradailynews.com/?p=725):
*Mrs.Annamma Skariah, Kizhakkedath (Chicago) left to her heavenly abode*

Comment: Thank you Kris, yes it's so common in India, I mistook it as an English phrase.

Comment: Being common in India doesn't mean it can't be English.

Comment: @Sripriya It's your English, too!

Answer (score 0):

If, as seems probable, the expression *left for heaven* is a euphemism for *died*, then it might be used by some religious believers. But a much more common euphemism for *to die* among believers and atheists alike is *to pass away*.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of Hindu culture we say in Gujarat "સ્વર્ગે  સીધાવ્યા અથવા સ્વર્ગમાં ઉપડ્યા " so meaning of "left for heaven " is easily conveyed to people of Gujarat and probably to all Hindus across India.

Comment: The question was asking if this was a common phrase for native English speakers - your answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @KillingTime Aren't there a lot of native English speakers in India? Because if they are, I think it does address the question. The Gujarat phrase should have been in the question itself, though.

Comment: @Conrado What percentage of the people of Gujarat speak English as their first language? While I suspect that a large number use it as a second language, they aren't what I'd consider to be 'native English speakers'.

Comment: @KillingTime I actually don't know anyone that speaks Gujarat. I was just thinking about Indian English when you posted your first comment, and I wrote what I was thinking. You're right, second languages aren't native in any sense.